# .NET Core Console include specific folder when publishing

Tags: .net-core

I want to include a specific folder and its subdirectories when I publish the .NET Core Console application. I added the following code in the `Properties/PublishProfiles/FolderProfile.pubxml` file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <_CustomFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/../Templates/**/*" />
    <DotNetPublishFiles Include="@(_CustomFiles)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>Templates/%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
    </DotNetPublishFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

but this code does not work.

The weird thing is that, those code works when I publish my .NET Core Web API project.
Is there any difference for the configuration between Web API and .NET Core Console?

Answer (score 0):

What i actually do is to update the item's build profile which allows the respective folder and the contents included in the publish directory as well.

Something like this below appears in the .csproj file

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="depends\Bitmap1.bmp">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```